# How to Build Audio File Stream iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, audio, audio-streaming

I need some guidance on how to make a audio stream app for multiple audio files, so the app user can choose from the list and listen to the item.Do you know any good tutorials, or place from where i can learn how to do this by my self. I'm familiar with the concept on how it wood look like, i need something on how to pause and resume, how to go to next and previous are there some classes that can help me do this. Can someon help me?

Comment: Do you mean by multiple, the user can play more than one file at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into AVQueuePlayer if you can require your users to run iOS 4.1+.  It can help you stream a sequential playlist of items.  AVPlayer is another option, which only requires iOS 4.0+, but it can only handle one item at a time, so you'd have to write your own code to manage the playlist.

The [AV Foundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/02_Playback.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH3-SW4) does a pretty good job of explaining how to use these classes.

Comment: can multiple users use it? Like maybe  10-20 users at a same time want to listen to "item_03" can they do this , or only the first request can get to stream from that item

Comment: That isn't impacted in any way by your iOS client implementation.  It depends entirely upon the scalability and bandwidth of the server that's hosting your content.